# Compile Clojure?

Tags: java, clojure, compilation

I am new to clojure and I have tried to compile it last night but I couldn't seem to do it and I have no idea. I am on windows and don't know much about java. I just want a stand-alone file that I can give to my friends. (I know they need java) Can anyone help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use [Leiningen](http://github.com/technomancy/leiningen). You can make a very simple project.clj file for your project with :main pointing to your main file's namespace, and then you could do 'lein uberjar' on the command-line and it would stick all your dependencies in a single executable jar file.

I'll point out that every file that needs to be compiled must have a namespace with :gen-class enabled. For example:

```
(ns whatever.main
  (:gen-class))
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about Leiningen.

Comment: @GummyBEARZ Well, I do try. ;)

Answer (score 2):

How about an [all in one Clojure installer](http://clojure.bighugh.com/) for Windows? Unless I misunderstood your question and you want your Clojure files themselves compiled.

If you want to compile your own Clojure files, you can read [this explanation](http://clojure.org/compilation) on the Clojure site.

Comment: Ok, added some info in my answer

Answer (score 1):

for producing a stand alone clojure program Leiningen's uberjar option does just that! Install leiningen and then run:

```
lein uberjar
```

and you get a single file that your friends can use to run your program.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a gradle user, you might be interested in [Clojuresque](http://kotka.de/blog/2010/01/Clojuresque_1.3.0_released.html) (source [at bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org/kotarak/clojuresque)). It provides similar to leiningen an ueberjar task, which packages up all necessary dependencies in a single jar. It allows easy compilation as well as simple deployment to Clojars. (Although this does currently not work on Windows.)

Comment: Clojuresque was the first time I had ever heard of Gradle. I need to try it out sometime. The idea of build scripts in Groovy don't exactly excite me though. :)

Comment: Gradle makes it very easy to have multiproject builds. Killer-feature for me. The Groovy part... who cares? Build scripts in Clojure also don't blow me off the chair.